# Numpy calculations always differ per function call inside loop for SVD reconstruction

Tags: numpy, vectorization, matrix-multiplication, svd

my function that tries to reconstruct an image using SVD with 3 loops sometimes yields different results and tries to calculate the reconstructed image with bad values. Sometimes it works completely fine but if I repeatedly try to reconstruct the same image with the same parameters, it eventually shows bad results. This happens at random and probably not due to variables not being overwritten/deleted correctly after each function call. Sometimes I also get this error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:21: RuntimeWarning: invalid 
value encountered in add
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py:452: RuntimeWarning: overflow 
encountered in double_scalars
  dv = np.float64(self.norm.vmax) - np.float64(self.norm.vmin)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py:455: RuntimeWarning: invalid 
value encountered in double_scalars
  newmin = vmid - dv * fact
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/colors.py:1026: RuntimeWarning: 
overflow encountered in double_scalars
  resdat /= (vmax - vmin)
```

Here is my code which reproduces this bug: https://www.kaggle.com/krajnovic/numpy-variance

I debugged it for quite some time and I think the issue happens at the last summation of the "reco" object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't paste your relevant code from kaggle here, so I am pasting it here for you.

#### Your code:

```
import os
import imageio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = imageio.imread("/kaggle/input/numpy-variance111/m1-1_slice125.png")
im = im -im.min() / im.max() - im.min()
u,s,vt = np.linalg.svd(im, full_matrices=False)
k = 20

def reconstruct_svd_for_loops3(u,s,vt,k):
    """SVD reconstruction for k components using 3 for-loops
    for + in svd for zeile for spalte
    Inputs:
    u: (m,n) numpy array
    s: (n) numpy array (diagonal matrix)
    vt: (n,n) numpy array
    k: number of reconstructed singular components
    
    Ouput:
    (m,n) numpy array U_mk * S_k * V^T_nk for k reconstructed components
    """
    ### BEGIN SOLUTION
    reco = np.empty(u.shape)
    for i in range(k): #for k components
        sum_ = np.empty(u.shape)
        for j in range(u[:,i].shape[0]): #for each element in ith column of u
            for k in range(vt[i,:].shape[0]): #for each element in ith row of vt
                sum_[j,k] = u[j,i] * vt[i,k]
        sum_ = s[i] * sum_
        reco += sum_
    ### END SOLUTION
    del sum_
    return reco
```

#### Errors and corrections

I have found some errors in your code, but only the first listed error is the one causing the randomness.

1. The reason it works sometimes and sometimes not is because you are using `np.empty`, which initializes your `reco` and `sum_` arrays to garbage values ranging from `-inf` to `inf`. Thus sometimes when are lucky you may happen to initialize with values that doesn't crash. You can fix thus by using `np.zeros` instead.
2. <strike>Additionally, you are specifying incorrect shapes and you have also implemented your [outer prdouct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) (the two inner loops) incorrectly. This does not cause the randomness though, but your reconstruction will be incorrect. *See code below*.</strike> Your code was fine. I misread some things the first time.
3. Your image normalization is wrong, you are missing some parenthesis'. *See code below*.
4. This isn't an error, but a suggestion; you can easily write all of this without any loops by utilizing NumPy [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [matrix multiplication](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html). *See code below*:

#### Implementation of fixes and suggestions

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from urllib import request
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

url = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/656159226805399552/v6ffWuIc_400x400.jpg"
img = np.array(Image.open(request.urlopen(url))) # Image of owl

def normalize_image(X: np.ndarray):
    xmin = X.min()
    xmax = X.max()
    return (X - xmin) / (xmax - xmin)

X = img[..., 0] # Pick a single channel
X = normalize_image(X)

def reconstruct_loops(u, s, vt, k):
    reco = np.zeros(u.shape)
    for i in range(k): #for k components
        sum_ = np.zeros(u.shape)
        for j in range(u[:,i].shape[0]): #for each element in ith column of u
            for k in range(vt[i,:].shape[0]): #for each element in ith row of vt
                sum_[j,k] = u[j,i] * vt[i,k]
        sum_ = s[i] * sum_
        reco += sum_
    return reco

def reconstruct_vectorized(u, s, vt, k):
    return (u[:,:k]*s[:k])@vt[:k,:]

k = 10
u, s, vt = np.linalg.svd(X, full_matrices=False)
reco_loop = reconstruct_loops(u, s, vt, k)
reco_vector = reconstruct_vectorized(u, s, vt, k)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3)
axes[0].set_title("Original")
axes[0].set_axis_off()
axes[0].imshow(X, cmap='gray')
axes[1].set_title("Using\nloops")
axes[1].set_axis_off()
axes[1].imshow(normalize_image(reco_loop), cmap='gray')
axes[2].set_title("Using numpy broadcasting\nand matrix\nmultiplication")
axes[2].set_axis_off()
axes[2].imshow(normalize_image(reco_vector), cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image: recons]

Comment: thanks a lot for the details. the image normalization part wasnt even part of my own code, it was my teacher's lol and later on in this assignment im doing broadcasting for comparison and right now im trying to do this on my GPU using cuda but finally it works now consistently with np.zeros!

Comment: @Fenrir I am glad I could help! I noticed that your outer product implementation was fine. I messed up some things when I tested around which made me believe that your function was faulty (I was truncating the u, s and vt matrices in the global namespace, which messed up your logic). I have corrected myself in my answer, apologies for that.